Expected Value in Random Sampling with Replacement and Variable Probability
There are $n$ white balls in an urn. We draw one ball with replacement. If it is white, we paint it red before putting it back. Let $X$ be the random variable representing the number of red balls in the urn after $k$ draws. Find the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X]$.
Let $X_i$ be a random variable such that:
$$
X_i = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if a white ball is drawn in the } i\text{-th draw}, \\
0 & \text{if a red ball is drawn in the } i\text{-th draw}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $X = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_{k}$.
By the linearity of expectation, we have:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] + \mathbb{E}[X_2] + \ldots + \mathbb{E}[X_{k}]. $$
For each $i \leq k$, we have:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_i] = 1 \cdot P(X_i = 1) + 0 \cdot P(X_i = 0) = P(X_i = 1), $$
so
$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{k} P(X_i = 1). $$
Let $R_i$ denote the number of red balls in the urn after the $i$-th draw. Note that $R_i = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_{i-1}$ and $R_1 = 0$, hence:
$$ P(X_i = 1) = \frac{n - R_{i-1}}{n} = 1 - \frac{ \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} X_j}{n}. $$
However, looking for $R_i$ brings us back to the original problem. On the other hand, it is the only approach I have come up with. My main issue is finding $P(X_i = 1)$. Thank you in advance for your help.

You need to specify the initial distribution of colors.  Are they all white at the start?  Something else?

hint:  if they are all white at the start, then the probability that a given ball is still white at the end of the $n^{th}$ round is easily computed.

Yes, you are right, I mistakenly did not write that they are all white at the beginning. I have edited the post.

As per Lulu's hint in the comments, let $X_{i}=1$ if the $i$-th ball is never picked in any of the $k$ draws  and $X_{i}=0$ if it is picked up atleast once before the end of $k$ draws.
Then $P(X_{i}=1)=(\frac{n-1}{n})^{k}$ .
Hence the number of white balls is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ and the number of red balls is $n-\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ .
So $E(n-\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i})=n-n(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k}$

Let $Y_i$ be the number of red balls after $i$th draw. Then
$$
Y_i \mid Y_{i-1} \sim Y_{i-1}+\text{Bernoulli}\left(1-\frac{Y_{i-1}}n\right). 
$$
So $$\mathbb{E}\left(Y_i\mid Y_{i-1}\right) = 1+ \frac{n-1}{n} Y_{i-1},$$ and $$
\mathbb{E}\left(Y_i\right)=1+ \frac{n-1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{i-1}\right).$$
With initial condition $\mathbb{E}(Y_0)=0$, the above recurrent relation solves to
$$\mathbb{E}(Y_k)=n\left[1-\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^k\right].
$$
